# JavaScript - conditionally call a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I want my backend Node.js API to be generic, I would like to let clients determine for themselves if they want a 'lean' MongoDB query or a full query.

In order to just get back JSON (actually, POJSOs, not JSON), we use lean() like so:

```
Model.find(conditions).limit(count).lean().exec(function (err, items) {});
```

however, what if I wanted to conditionally call lean()?

```
if(isLean){

 Model.find(conditions).limit(count).lean().exec(function (err, items) {});

else(){

 Model.find(conditions).limit(count).exec(function (err, items) {});

}
```

this is not that big of a deal to have two different calls, but imagine if we had more than one conditional, not just `isLean`, then we would have a factorial thing going on where we had many many calls, not just 2 different ones.

So I am wondering what is the best way to conditionally call `lean()` - my only idea is to turn lean into a no-op if `isLean` is false...

this would involve some monkey-patching TMK -

```
function leanSurrogate(isLean){
  if(isLean){
    return this.lean();
  }
  else{
   return this;
 }
}
```

anyone have something better?

(or perhaps the mongoose API already has this: `lean(false)`, `lean(true)`...and defaults to true...)

Comment: You answer your own question.... :) http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Comment: you're right, thanks! good for mongoose, but would still like to know if there is an answer for this if that were not the case :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. You don't have to restrict yourself to using one long series of method calls in one shot.

You can break it up where you need to, allowing you to avoid duplicating code:

```
var query = Model.find(conditions).limit(count);

if (isLean) {
    query = query.lean();
}

query.exec(function (err, items) {});
```

Comment: but one thing they say to do is to not use "inline functions" when possible

Comment: @AlexMills Who is "they" and what are you referring to by "inline functions"? It doesn't seem that you're talking about [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) which are the only type of inline functions I know of.

Comment: @AlexMills Ok, I've read it, but I still don't see what part of my example you are taking issue with. Petka doesn't even make clear what he means by "inline functions", but he appears to be referring to closures. I haven't introduced any closures into your code.

Comment: yeah I actually have no idea what he was referring to