# Can I conditionally pass a property into an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to conditionally pass a property into an object-based function:

```
myFunction
      .x()
      .y()
      .x();
```

Here, I'd like to only pass in `y()` based on a condition, something like:

```
myFunction
      .x()
      [isTrue && y()]
      .x();
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: The pattern you're presenting is called *method chaining*. But I'm afraid the requested solution is not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - conditionally call a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455507/javascript-conditionally-call-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that syntax if you wanted to choose between different methods dynamically. But there's no "do nothing" method that you can substitute in place of `y` when the condition is false.

Use an `if` statement instead.

```
let temp = myFunction.x();
if (isTrue) {
    temp = temp.y();
}
temp.x()
```

Comment: When the condition is false I suppose you could do `() => myFunction` but yeah why would you 

Comment: Good call. If it can't be done inline, this should do the trick. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that is more like what you originally imagined.  Barmar's solution will work just fine, but I thought I'd show a different approach more like you imagined:

```
obj
  .x()
  [doIt ? "y" : "noop"]()
  .x();
```

In this scheme, `doIt` is any boolean or boolean expression and `.noop()` is a "do nothing" method on the object.

And, here's a working example you can run in a snippet:

```js
const obj = {
    x() {
        console.log("executing x() method");
        return this;
    },
    y() {
        console.log("executing y() method");
        return this;
    },
    noop() {
        console.log("executing noop() method");
        return this;
    }
}

// try both values of the boolean
for (let doIt of [true, false]) {
    console.log(`\nresults for doIt = ${doIt}`);
    obj
        .x()
        [doIt ? "y" : "noop"]()
        .x();
}
```